# Assert.AreEqual() for objects Fail

Tags: c#, nunit

Assert.AreEqual() fails for 2 same objects.
Getting error as ::
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:. Actual:.

Below is the sample:

```
[TestMethod]
public void testMultiplication()
{ 
    Dollar five = new Dollar(5);
    Assert.AreEqual(new Dollar(10), five.times(2));
    Assert.AreEqual(new Dollar(15), five.times(3));
}

class Dollar
{
    private int amount;

    public Dollar(int amount)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Dollar times(int multiplier)
    {
        return new Dollar(amount * multiplier);
    }

    public bool equals(Object obj)
    {
        Dollar dollar = (Dollar) obj; 
        return amount == dollar.amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Equals` is not the same as `equals`. You're never using your implementation. This is why you use `override` in your method declaration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to *override* `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `Dollar`.  The defaults compare reference equality so your two different instances will not be the same.  Your current `equals` method will not be used.

A simple implementation:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Dollar dollar = (Dollar) obj; 
    return amount == dollar.amount;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return amount;
}
```

As an aside, though I recognise the code is almost verbatim from *Test Driven Development by Example*, in C# the [convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is that methods and properties are Pascal cased, so `TestMultiplication`, `Times`, `Equals` etc.  Maybe something to consider as you're continuing.

Comment: +1. Overriding Equals has its pitfalls though. Like having to override GetHashCode as well, or that you shouldn’t really do it for mutable types, and that if you do it you should really override the == operator. The [docs on the Equals method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) sum it up nicely. Using a custom Comparer in the `Assert.AreEqual` call could be a lot easier. May also be easier to customize a custom comparer to what your test needs than it is to make your tests work around the Equals override implementation.